# KO: wait for function to finish before putting the value to the observable

Tags: knockout.js

is there a way to wait for a function to finish before getting the value of the variable from it and place it to the observable?

i have code like this:

```
    var poop = {};
    retrievePoop(function(){//put an array to the variable poop});
    self.eatPoop = ko.observable(poop);
```

i was hoping that when i declare the variable poop in self.eatPoop it would contain the new value from the function retrievePoop but when console log it just displays an empty object.

Comment: can you show some code for your `retrievePoop` function? And is it an async function?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create the observable first and update it:

```
self.eatPoop = ko.observable({});
retrievePoop(function(){
    //some code
    self.eatPoop(newPoopValue);
});
```